# Android in-app purchases: do you need to check for the com.android.vending.BILLING permission when targeting Android 6?

Tags: android, permissions, in-app-purchase, android-6.0-marshmallow

When implementing in-app billing, or IAB, the [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-permission) say you have to add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

As of Android 6, apps are [expected to check](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) at runtime if users have granted permissions that don't belong to the '[normal](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html)' permissions category. Note that, as at API level 23, `com.android.vending.BILLING` isn't listed anywhere under this category. So...

1. If it isn't normal, does that mean it's dangerous?
2. Do I need to check for permission before using IAB?
3. If I do, how? I can't find any examples of IAB integrated with the new Android 6 permissions model. There doesn't appear to be any permission related to billing under [`Manifest.permission`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) for example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't find `com.android.vending.BILLING` permission in the list of normal or dangerous permissions of Android 6.0 because it isn't a system permission.

It is declared by the package `com.android.vending` (a.k.a. Google Play Store). You can find it in his `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"
    android:description="@string/perm_billing_desc"
    android:label="@string/perm_billing_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.NETWORK"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
```

You don't need to check the permission at runtime because it is necessary only to the system permissions.

You can find more information about application declared permission here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Comment: That's music to my ears - thanks! Please could you add the link to that manifest; I couldn't find that. So basically it's safe to assume at runtime that my app will have all the necessary permissions to use in-app billing? Except I do also use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` to associate a user's purchase with their Google account. So I guess I'll have to check for that anyway, since that *is* a dangerous permission (see Table 1 under http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't link the manifest because it's not available online. I had to decompile the Play Store APK to extract the `AndroidManifest.xml` . Yes you guess right, you need to request the `GET_ACCOUNTS ` permission at runtime.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. Rats - I'll have to do the checking and requesting of the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, then. But at least I'll only have to check for the one permission rather than for `BILLING` as well, thanks to you!